# How to paint wall with residual paint left from adhesive poster?

Tags: painting, repainting

I recently purchased a property and in one of the rooms the old owners had a large wall poster, stuck with adhesive directly to the wall. Where this has been removed, it has taken large amounts of the paint with it, exposing the bare plaster (which is in good condition).

How do I best go about painting this wall to achieve a good finish? I'd like to avoid lining paper if possible.

[image: The wall needing painting.]

Answer (score 6):

1. Scrape away any loose paint and adhesive.
2. Wash the wall to remove the bulk of the remaining adhesive.
3. Optionally prime the surface to seal it, depending on how chalky or contaminated it seems.
4. Skim with joint compound to restore smoothness. Use minimal compound thickness. It should be almost translucent until it dries.
5. Sand lightly with a block or plate to remove imperfections and improve flatness.
6. Repeat steps 4 and 5 until the desired surface is achieved. Use light at a low angle to see flaws.
7. Spray texture, if desired.
8. Prime (*again*, if done earlier).
9. Paint.

Answer (score 2):

It depends upon what you mean by a "good finish": which could mean decent, OK, perfect, etc.   If it where me doing this, I'd skim coat it with a finish mud normally used for drywall. Then apply what ever texture you want, presumably to match the rest of the room (smooth wall? Orange peel?  Knockdown?). Make sure it's clean and no loose paint remains. Also make sure any remaining adhesive is removed.
Given the size of the area, those touch up cans of texture won't do it.  You'll probably need to either buy or rent a hopper to apply the desired texture.

A couple of pieces of advice:  If you decide to DIY get a wide taping knife so you and feather it nicely.   Next: Applying a texture (if not smooth-wall) isn't easy to get perfect, you might want to practice on some scrap sheetrock to get the hang of it. That's esp. true if you're doing a knock-down, practice first!

Once you're happy with the finish/texture, prime and paint.

Comment: You talk about texture in 3 different places. You might want to edit to put all the thoughts together and in order of operations. All good info, just a bit confusing.